# Angle between $\vec a$ and $\vec b $.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We got the same size vector $\vec a$ and $\vec b $.
We know that the vector $\vec a +2\vec  b$ and $5\vec a-4\vec b$ are perpendicular?

$(\vec a +2\vec b) \perp (5 \vec a-4\vec b)$

What is angle between $\vec a$ and $\vec b $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
(\vec{a} + 2 \vec{b})\cdot(5\vec a-4\vec b) = 0\\
5 \|\vec a\|^2-4(\vec a\cdot\vec b)+10(\vec a\cdot\vec b)-8\|\vec b\|^2 = 0\\
6(\vec a\cdot\vec b)=3\|\vec a\|^2 \\
\frac{(\vec a\cdot\vec b)}{\|\vec a\|\|\vec b\|} = \frac{1}{2} \\
\cos \theta = \frac{1}{2} \\
$$

So angle between the vectors is $\frac{\pi}{3}$. (Note that I have used the fact that they are of same size twice.)

Answer (score 1):

since $\vec a+2\vec b$ is perpendicular to $5\vec a-4\vec b $

we have  $(\vec a+2\vec b)$.$(5\vec a-4\vec b )=0$,

$=5 \vec |a|^2-4 \vec a.\vec b+10\vec a.\vec b+-8|\vec b|^2=-3|\vec a|^2+6\vec a.\vec b=0$
$\text{   }$  $($since $|\vec a|=|\vec b|)$

which gives $3|\vec a|^2=6|\vec a|^2\cos\theta$

or, $\cos\theta=\frac12\implies\theta=\frac{\pi}3$

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$(\vec{a} + 2\vec{b})\cdot (5\vec{a}-4\vec{b}) = 5\|\vec{a}\|^2 +6\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}-8\|\vec{b}\|^2 = 6\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}-3\|\vec{a}\|^2$$

Thus, if those two vectors are perpendicular, then $6\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}-3\|\vec{a}\|^2 = 0\implies \vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=\frac{\|\vec{a}\|^2}{2}$.

Computing the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ should be straightforward from here.

Answer (score 0):

Denote what you call the size of $a$ and $b$ by $r$. Then $0=(a+2b,5a-4b)=5(a,a)+6(a,b)-8(b,b)=5r^{2}+6r^2\cos (\alpha )-8r^{2}$ showing that $\cos (\alpha )=1/2$.